# Do while em python

Tags: python-3.x, loop, sintaxe

Existe algum comando semelhante ao do while de c e Java na linguagem python?
Estou entrando na linguagem agora e já desenvolvia em java aí me surgiu essa dúvida

Answer (score 12):

Não, mas praticamente todo loop na maioria das linguagens pode ser feito de várias maneiras.

Pseudocódigo:

```
do:
  fazCoisa()
  while condicaodesejadaparacontinuar
```

Escrevendo em Py:

```
while True:
  fazCoisa()
  if not condicaodesejadaparacontinuar:
    break
```

Ou seja, em vez de fazer e dar loop se verdadeiro, invertemos para fazer sempre (`while True`) até que seja falsa a condição desejada (`break` para quebrar o loop).

Answer (score 6):

Não!

Mas você pode `Simular` um do while...

> Linguagem C:

```
int i = 1;

do{
  printf("%d\n", i);
  i = i + 1;
} while(i <= 3);
```

> Python:

```
i = 1

while True:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    if(i > 3):
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Não propriamente.

While:
O comando while faz com que um conjunto de instruções seja executado enquanto uma condição é atendida. Quando o resultado dessa condição passa a ser falso, a execução do loop é interrompida, como mostra o exemplo a seguir:

```
    contador = 0
    while (contador < 5):
           print(contador)
           contador   = contador + 1

    contador = 0
    while (contador < 5):
           print(contador)
           contador = contador + 1
    else:
           print("O loop while foi encerrado com sucesso!")
```

While - Else: 
Ao final do while podemos utilizar a instrução else. O propósito disso é executar alguma instrução ou bloco de código ao final do loop,